# How to query for objects that are not already in an array (refreshing for an array) using parse.com service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, querying

I have a table view that is being populated with an array that is holding strings. This array receives its data from a cloud database on parse.com. It populates successfully in the beginning. I have a refresh button at the bottom of my view controller that is supposed to add all the new objects in the database that are not already in the array. I tried to do this by sending `whereKey:notContainedIn:` to a query object. But it doesn't fetch any of the new objects. Here is my code for the refresh method. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) refresh {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Employee"];
    [query whereKey:@"Employee" notContainedIn:currentEmployees]; 
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
                [employees addObject:object];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                    [hvc.tableView reloadData];
                });
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

edit: It's fetching objects now, but it's grabbing everything that was already in the database and adding them again. So if i had a list of

```
- dog 
- cat
```

and I added bird to the database online, I would get:

```
- dog 
- cat 
- dog 
- cat 
- bird
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `whereKey:notContainedIn:`, the `key` should be a field on your `Employee`. If you're following naming conventions, what you've actually supplied is the object name itself. And it looks like you supply an array of objects. You should have an `identity` field (or something similar) and and you should be supplying an array of identities to `whereKey:notContainedIn:`. You can get the array of identities with:

```
NSArray *identities = [currentEmployees valueForKey:@"identity"];
```

(substitute the appropriate filed name in place of `identity`)

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this. So I have to make an array, fill it with the names of all the employees, and use that? I feel that that is inefficient. Is there an easier way to update an array, or is this the way of doing it?

Comment: The code I show will get the names of the employees for you from the array you already have (if you change `identity` to `name`)